# Infer Correct Return Type of Subclasses for Method

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I have the following class hierarchy

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&target=7#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgIQKYAsCGA3Y0DKArgEYBWqAxvAL5wBmUEIcA5FAB6kDOLA3AFD8A9ACox4iZKnSZsufIUj%20cEXGWqAgsS4womKgGEIAO10QANgFkIAE1Tn1ip85evxQ-qnaRYcTNt19eApzTC4uOC0dPUMTMytbewAeABUAPkRBODgwRhhKfJs4KFRMGxNzAE84AH1sTHNgG2AYSoMsYwBzVAA5CBhgOmBUKDgAXjhjVAB3FAwcPCgiMgKk4ggLUuM0gApdQlQASgFs3P6C1CKSsorquoaD9swu3v7B4dGJqdm0LFwCEjkKipXbGQjmczHLI5PIXIo1YBcABqDSa4zg%201QJxh5yol1qiIAClBEQMpujMdj-NEgnBujAUeYDjtDgAuOApKkBGLwLioBkPVA7b6Mg7slJsuDYCBNLk0qjFVB8mAs9nS2XQokknTAKYszLZbIlGCEKDGDHoREAOgRXGJpN1WOUcGomuRqJs%20oQzqN-NN5pglq4NsRjI12VdzvqjWarSeLy4Xp9ipNZot1vuMZabQ63T6AyGIytYQA8toRvViOYhVCI9Do49c0qk4aU-708HM43nnm3oWoMWuGW%20VBK9WWdjI9kQltCGAW4bAxno01s-HewWPlaKEwwNX8hPk0vOw3UOvXpuizvwPua5PoXYwKhjDYh8Yds9%20ugRkZTIxzOyUSBLEf4WNYdjmEkzyVGkhwGoan6Bj%20cT-laK6xjmPbNocybZFaXAkFwFAksQQreq2rZTOwMDsqGHrjBk5EUa2gxwDsdExnAACEYwTMeIbujGcFMcxrb8Zmq5xk2%20bvEWVEqhxTS1qJYlBlaJTKoeKl1tpHYCWGRQTIpNjYsxrpmcpkaRqIbi2XZ9nqGoKhwAAYtAIAaFAeiVOB9iOPZAWBfIHheD4wShOErnuZ53m%20ZBKTotBGRePkL4REBPK-vEcWpAA2gAuox0K5MA9T5IqNzGFUBLGOhblQCAWX-hEXwzHA%20D8kkGVBE1YGJPFaS7FCzo7sY0SEFQ0A7CVZWoBV5RVXco3xFwgHcj1KF9RBIIFeiBXCcmBFPlAh7JnQ0BsaNOhwMt-5wBAdC1LdFhcAdzHicQuo2CkEC9eYOzPZCpkusmrF7GptoGW9FHiae54yf2VryeD1r0qKNbKTpIPOjNmDlTUn0vj9f0A5tAGROtIHZf1ILQ9OZNoR6a5NomOHMfhhHEcApE7CJFHyey%20pjBk4kmAZzNYZ6gNsxR1CYzdDNwyzLK4XAHPaFzPN85RKWC3Bwt6V2Z7SX2W7I-xaOCiyMutnLwNg1xgNWsZ1vwapGbGeidANHywPZOJup1e5f3BmUUtk-L5nY6cJKzbUYtM1Jkuk6B5PdVT-45ekdNwGDTsu4cOf%20xDgcevVjVk8GEH8kK0vA7Q9h8m7i4l7VZfB5XxY2OHqeR8mV3wLkqD-IQgmSZU%20AwHjo8UiXY8mUec8GbPHttzG5ch-hwAAF5zbxEwAAz24900lCP8-ZpP08RDxfFLx6Nst8uieYS8CNmylKOdsZlnQpbTI1mbsads4lAbBhAJgecgMGIK1Tlaf%20zJC73mdMqdGwoZjo3FPtZuYMRSCitNWLogZuK8UNmAghz5OiBiLhaRgsxvhwAAKJeSmgAA3Ln4LymBqggH6iwCIDDTxwHKEqSY-Q4B-DmqgAAjoQBocBCFUPQArcAmAShFBgBAG6poSimClIKVhfdWznVGDsfcucXxeHREfCxdh2BwCSJMDB%20DFGBl4LYrwABqTxNDQGV1yl9Lw%20V8L8jQXggBATLHsHykY6O9Avp-SSIwuAKVnyvgpvKGAf0s4ZAmBvMmOTdiBPYOyMEIBSJQElMkvmDt2JRIsWQyuhdVaBjoU42YzDGAnVYQASXqQAIgACQIGKdQfpwiICiOMOIrwpIGnHnoO5Th3k4C8IgoY4GwC0x%20NTlwSJdj8p%20AiIw5B2QIowCSSk6iaT0qUyyQUmm6R0TlwAOKMDnIU1UTCgF%20m2RDMBuUdkrQoUQ5RABaOAABGQ5YQmGnJutWZ4c4FzZCOleRFYJ5zyxMZdEw11oEPUabsx%209M4EziRVi%20FYBR7oBJoDNamTsmPNgs3IFzUrTUq4OgFO8R5YfS%20sTMmPL-y-2dBpfkKLFmmIHrA%20I91HpspeiS2VqFxUqlFdkLUDo9Q5y2QGf5ndh4jEqMKiwMD852m1GSDGyDIyeG8NAeAup8hQG9hQOaBk8Z4GMAAJSVOCeATFjLsnWJsZ42IRhdMsEqLgmBujsmiLqToAhIyhUdRiSoT44Ces0Z8XFqcGXAXuanHKSV9YZBzd6v1BFzAwAEDZIKjam1iEco5fJJb%20r%20Wbd2%20yIUHW%20BCGECI7bqbbQShMJKVzUrpPTsW0dyQnnehxrHPGc0aiRugKtOAiaui7S%20OCcwAhl2lVXU9HRz4BQAPFEe0l41JonVxuVa4C1qoImMC0YADRMEcgADQwhPfjdCeNN0AH52Q5ugNgvmaKTrDXdp2Cg57TDo3RG%20j9X7BQ3qfsGVBVs0MDAwwAjV27QlW3CWKDkOcZVD3PuLVoV8TQtUNsZYGAdLXar3vQH2ToWIn1hh6YDUBXrN1vfAb2wBqw2ErXileJ4BO5vAZAnYQHc0wJU1NY8zSVJWiGLWkYOwNIBpgVxQztbnbz3lpqk%204nJPSbGiCpRcAMgHxocXD288vbcb9thm0G6hOeYk5cOzin5ymfgAbMLVo-PRvCHGo43mG7mCbtrHzkN6J8SgAcbzbnOx%20aY2CCECXkxRys2xGjeBR50YnlPRjJC77uahiJw26EJZv1NnJT%20bGob11Bnx%20%20QkmugKQ5eg46JyM8ZhhDJWWF34deol-G0iGvIXvRrEqcdJSMAMlXqshw30bwvpCklhQntu-P1RmPL8Kw4QZOupqA4H5PQBzg7fjMZBOvRaVNx7-mJgFVY19t7CmOU0uU99%20W1Gz4VYvvRmrM96vf3nv9hr6X9GA400GQ45mDLHzYl1%20it8YTDyh1Vhjo9lWvfHvDdrA5zb9aUvCtVkqIdE4gJVl%20pOmN45jEjhH9odTkgy1lxe1pcNbYDu%20gj5hVs49PiztnWYYfXzq8xizg2AeU5NpeGnnW6c2DW4IayPajd2Vbc5V57ywBxS7cbm3Cg%201hQRUOqKDU3ms8t8yqdNyMlFqZWOoqx647PtuDVIODUQ5jbah1C5s7ffJCSkNbEj65pB8WrUIREwEC0FhZyaEA9Mv3tPgB5PpQX1LUruyBAuUADSDSADWqBKiEpSPlQtmUHljur4VOWzcYOnV42xGoYCaE4pTtdXKgMeiYBAKgP9gNDmErLECGAUW-zDETIPpprmiUrXH2TSf0-DkTEBtlw2hNvq-SFRPqfM%20VVmthdBSzINbbQnW0n2oZ-BWp1NeYffqAE26CTVnzJlbw2g7W2jLWbidhayTgTBVnZgIg1hIjIlVmyAFjYnLUNgTgV1fm6B7l5VVjtn7kVkFHPFZlVnViIiQN5hQKcWokFlPHZAfxgVFmMD%20nRnPDwP-F-z-VPGVUIPgxtFPF31Tl-0P1v3MHgU20QRl0dgZgLl8V108ySwmwELfVDwrl2S7k4IsH1wD1PRqCwI12TnpW9zbzALj2MBgmexPgtQMldhS3F3UM3mrgPDrmKxSWULV1XicM7jDm-1iVE0J1o3Z1h0511x530hR0cPbjD07i4B3j3lISPl6zK0h1Z2h2qyVwJy5yUi8Lk2wKpy1yRh12RyEh6zrD0PxhMDYJIKbG0J-2v3-xJC6B4MFEYMsJzjYz52tSUN9mF3yIOGEPiFEPRFPAiKNkKNkm13mxSyGK4Ovxb1RwOHcPvw6IOykMAT5h21eyFwqNRQ2PQWmG-QlGbhHxlTmIsG4KWNQHn0ekXwKBXwAObHG0LiaxlWgXh0W38SvwP28wdmlia2LjaQYU6TYT%20kmGvzgCGQQB%20NQDGQaQYRMWYCEREQEXER3GWy4EgBfAxC0WgiuW1U6ClWYDAQ2QINVidlF2ZF4PKLiXJUxUlRg23AxWRXlnuKoEZgAUTEVSS0xxMUYX0G5W-xAIzi2gsKsPNQZnpNZOIyGBfESRr1STSjgHr0b0enSGmjxnQC3RrwADJt0ACugc5zEPjt9mpcowAtSuB8oZDLTAxgxdQQhCA7BEwWArQWBXiUs84yZxhSFCBLE5TLgt9WkIB6E2pQTukABVYwfwasXEhRCACgU9aBaYFoZRGM6fKE4ZO07UsZMksyVWHbY-YrIgsaYIMmQkK09EHMnDPcFoHYN0j04GU0nkvZQGSs%200-CS0OgdVG0s6C6Ufcs1ODs5RQldsq0mhb01OX0iYf0uwQMvXQE2hUM9pJhY7HYVhaM2MuaTRBMpM8qFMtMiEzM6E8cwMeE3UHEY6VoHILUrMhAGsvMx-ErQ0MGBsuUmwP6FgBpaWLfU07-I5PwDonTBJS-CsrU58ks1sIssmK7buBUz3ZU1UpvXYWE9kPUg05ozoIAgtUw0A%20deKTvFlPmVsi4hog-dEaBVYyocYj-C-L-WEnC3lBnJUCVHOdk5fU8bkg1YlHTaAAUigIUkwmPdvcUllA2J2RnJBZ0KyQQYQW3BShQdQRyRhdgKfPcOaSM2Nboa3RSvS9wfgGVJE13OcCPWYc3N3OKag4xA9X-UpNqEdTOfqBsgACXsHMC0QAHVoBzAbAPS-0hAhA4A%20k6BI18RWgs1ERncND4gkgd1Og0gf1kww4NI%20Qt0GFy4YpuErLco4BArgrjBQrlsNFM05oorMquFKgkgEBohUB%20Qmik13EKBswGquheBqA0gaCMr3ITL3cIJeY8qgqQqwqSrIrh0eqLdqrar6rMLGqboWrZqugOqaDWxpqaJVzHKxT-oWBIUAAmAAZnal0DqpgH8pWsNGataHsvMo7nMO2oMGzA9JoLlmTBiX4EIMMrxTE1suv3BImGMotxAvlKFRYDoB%20unybKAA)

```
export abstract class AbstractControlModel<T> { ... }

export class FormArrayModel<T = any> extends AbstractControlModel<T[]> {
  constructor(private readonly _controls: AbstractControlModel<T>[] = []) { ... }

  findControl<E extends AbstractControlModel<T> = FormControlModel<T>>(index: number): E {
    if (!(index in this._controls))
      throw new Error(`Index "${index}" does not exist in this form array `);
    return this._controls[index] as E;
  }
}

export class FormGroupModel<T> extends AbstractControlModel<T>
  constructor(private _controls?: { [E in keyof T]: AbstractControlModel<T[E]> }) { ... }

  findControl<K extends keyof T>(name: K) {
    return this.controls.get(name);
  }
```

I create a `FormGroupModel` object

```
const formGroup = new FormGroupModel({
    fullName: new FormControlModel('Hello World'), // Inferred type is FormControlModel<string>,
    addresses: new FormArrayModel([ // Inferred type is FormArrayModel<{street: string; city: string;}>
        new FormGroupModel({ // Inferred type is FormGroupModel<{street: string; city: string}>
            street: new FormControlModel('123 Street'),
            city: new FormControlModel('City')
        })
    ])
});

const fullNameControl = formGroup.findControl('fullName'); // The returned type is AbstractControlModel<any> instead of FormControlModel<string>
```

When I call `findControl` on `formGroup` variable above, I want TypeScript to return an object of type `FormControl<string>` instead of `AbstractControl<any>`. How should I change the declarations to achieve this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please replace those `...` with something that compiles and demonstrates your issue?  Presumably you need `FormGroup<T>` to keep track of the types of controls for each property of `T`, but without some more concrete declarations for the class hierarchy I'm not sure how best to advise.  Unless you want other people to make something up, but then you're less likely to be happy with the answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Okay I made something up!  Hope it meets your needs!

Comment: @jcalz I added the full class definitions for them

Comment: Ideally a [mcve] would be just enough code to demonstrate the issue, preferably something that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

Comment: @jcalz Added link to a working playground

Answer (score 0):

As it's written currently, the type of `controls` is defined concretely as `{[K in keyof T]: AbstractControl<T[K]>}` meaning that fetching the key `K` on that type won't give you accurate type information for the actual value / class used, but the abstract type, so you are getting `any` or `unknown` instead.

Rather, you should make the type of `controls` generic, extending from that type, like so:

```
class FormGroup<T, C extends {[K in keyof T]: AbstractControl<T[K]>}> extends AbstractControl<T> {
    constructor(private controls: C) { ... }

    findControl<K extends keyof C>(name: K) {
        return this.controls[name];
    }
}
```

Notice that the type of `controls` is the new generic `C`, and `findControl` expects a key of `C`, not `T`.  This should allow TypeScript to properly determine the return type:

```
const formGroup = new FormGroup({
    fullName: new FormControl('Hello World'),
    addresses: new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
            street: new FormControl('123 Street'),
            city: new FormControl('City')
        })
    ])
})

// Correctly inferred as FormControl<string>
const fullNameControl = formGroup.findControl('fullName')
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=35&ssc=58&pln=15&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguacIGEB7AO2kOQB4AVAPgQG8EEBfAKFZTQwDFCoBbTFBgBPanQCmADwgTiAEwzZIMeEVJRy1ANoBdOo1ZMmsEioCu8PgAoADlACWAN2CykJMsjAAuLDlUEHpqUtHoAlAxGxtFg5rYSUNZhUUxsbByo6Ai8Auqe4gjSsgpK-nh5wQX0Ke7EFlaJ9s6uEgguyOYSvlQRhtExcQlJNWnsnFk5-ADimnHUADQI+IUycooM2gDSCA7ECADWEiKEAGYIVLq+yrhqQVpUW-rMkqslfirldyEGNaZ10JYIDYmi43H9PD4lr0EDUBvFEslouloiddvIKlptkU1hhDsczvgaNZiMB+F0EJterDjFAJBBzFA9hAABYOMAAOnBwTA2hJZN0AG4Rqx0n9IAgTnxprNbAgALwIYgSADu2SlM0IcWs1RR5mQyAAcqTyUrVZMMchrAByAASEn1hAQAHU+Mh5FawvMasB5PJaegJJDTWqBEJRNZtNSmMHJhqtTr+omVBI6b4Y1KLdaAIwAJgAzAgAMrQFMQD1exOJ2AOCAiNMqkP8TNW-A1kQeqMsRHGXTJZjJDhmRAnPWG40W+US9Uy9mohTNkf6o1kj1AA), with the `...`s replaced with `super()` so that the type checker doesn't complain.

Comment: I like this answer but I'm not sure if `T` is doing anything, as it is still inferred as `unknown`; you might want to get rid of it and just keep `C`.

Comment: I believe `T` is still necessary, since you need the `T` to be generic "inside" of `C` - it's okay that you're not directly assigning T as a type outside of the definition of `C`, it's still in use there.

Comment: `T` is being inferred as `unknown` in your example code, so it really isn't doing anything.  Remove `T` as a generic and replace all other `T` with `unknown` and you'll get the same behavior.  Furthermore, that means a constraint you think you're setting is not being set; your code, as it stands, validates things like `new FormGroup("somethingClearlyNotAcceptable")` because `C` isn't being constrained to anything.

Comment: Yeah, the type of the `FormGroup`'s value is being inferred as `unknown`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the generic `T` the type of `controls`, and compute the "plain" version from it, and not vice-versa.  Something like this:

```
class FormGroup<T extends Record<keyof T, AbstractControl<any>>> extends
  AbstractControl<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends AbstractControl<infer V> ? V : never }> {

  constructor(private controls: T) { super() }

  findControl<K extends keyof T>(name: K) {
    return this.controls[name];
  }
}
```

Here, the plain version is `{[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends AbstractControl<infer V> ? V : never}`, meaning you go through each control and see what type it represents.

You might do something similar with `FormArray` as well:

```
class FormArray<T extends AbstractControl<any>[]> extends
  AbstractControl<T[number] extends AbstractControl<infer V> ? V[] : never> {
  constructor(private controls: T) { super() }

  findControl<N extends number>(index: N) {
    return this.controls[index];
  }
}
```

And now your example looks like this:

```
const formGroup = new FormGroup({
  fullName: new FormControl('Hello World'),
  addresses: new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      street: new FormControl('123 Street'),
      city: new FormControl('City')
    })
  ])
});

const fullNameControl = formGroup.findControl('fullName'); // FormControl<string>
```

and even

```
const cityControl = formGroup.findControl('addresses').findControl(0)
  .findControl("city"); // FormControl<string>
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguacIGEB7AO2kOQB4AVAPgQG8EA3YZALgSoQF4FiBXZMgCECAL4BYAFDTpKNBgBihKAFtMUGAE9qCAKYAPCHuIATDNkgx4RUlHIVgxLTQDaAXTqHjZsNIRYONYEJGSUVK4CqiB6UO76RibmgVZ4tmEUAJbEAGaxCABqdAD8hR4IHMR6TLF09P5IJFb88CoAFAAOUJksxo125GAcVACUDAhg-B2xbWOSMlIBOdmm6faUAHIJPslRMVA0bSuGHBtj9YsBCFB6EPxQxAgQABaZYAB0sKHrYK7HBu4ANwNeZiBCyKTydAIZRqNYOWjbJIWIJpb4IuoNL7EZqtKCdbq9PTMVj8PTDc4TKYzObSeZyVDQ2GqADi9imum8yIQACU9F8oKYKABrPRaQg5TgAGhSuBs6MoThcNC8iV8DUscpCA0ojFcAGkENkEKLxZKqO5hgb4lzfLLgvDKNk8lBCiVChU+NV8mJMQsAtjcRB2l0esA+tiwkNOJTJtN8bT-QhlmZHRRDbbkqaJZxDsRgKpyQh9ecGgEbncHk9Xh9Iz9IgW9ECQXSIYHEDkVKz2R0eF6AO4wrtswhTNoXJaCZAbRuVPSD5mOtoAcgAEnohIQEAB1FTIUzLkZShrAUymG7oPTRqoLrsabRtVxlgdDtQjscTq4BKx6W5z29wgqK4AIwAEwAMwIAAytAv4QIex6XF+sCZBAWj-q+qhLsu+CoVoh7PmIIwNO4xFSERwILO2yZTjOhaOn2nZvj27wpqsQHLjktGNoegIIAA9PxmFplY2QAOY0BCchNIgKFoQxvBMd2o4dKxKzYae55XmAV6HmpqZAQADGRAT6exOptAARHJWiWSMfGCcJCoUKJxASUAA)

Comment: This doesn't make the subclass implementations of the 3 abstract methods pass because the abstract methods return/expect different types than the concrete implementations for some reason, but this looks very promising